# How to fix Scrolling while pressing an object that shrinks when pressing - SwiftUI

Tags: animation, button, swiftui, scroll

I've been trying to add a shrinking affect on buttons while they're being pressed, and I was able to establish it with with LongPressGesture

But at the same time, I noticed that this also stops the container from being scrolled when the box is pressed to start scrolling, for example, I can scroll when I press an empty space first to start scrolling, but I can't scroll when I press the box first to start scrolling.

I'm using Xcode 14.0.1 on macOS Monterey 12.6 and I tested the code both in virtual and physical phones running on iOS 16.

And here's a simplified version of my code,

```
struct TestView: View {
    
    @GestureState var isDetectingLongPress = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(spacing: 25) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.5, style: .continuous)
                    .fill(Color.blue)
                    .frame(height: 200)
                    .padding(25)
                    .scaleEffect(!isDetectingLongPress ? 1.0 : 0.875)
                    .brightness(!isDetectingLongPress ? 0.0 : -0.125)
                    .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.125), value: isDetectingLongPress)
                    .gesture(
                        LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 3)
                            .updating($isDetectingLongPress) { currentState, gestureState,
                                transaction in
                                gestureState = currentState
                                transaction.animation = Animation.easeIn(duration: 2.0)
                            }
                            .onEnded { finished in
                                
                            }
                    )
                
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Does my answer below answer the question? If so, please consider marking it as such.

Answer (score 2):

### Approach 1:

Add a modifier that delays the recognition of the tap gesture. If a user starts their scroll on the button, the user will still be able to scroll. The downside to this is if the user wants to tap the button, it will be slightly delayed.

This approach was found [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/a-guide-to-delaying-gestures-in-scrollview/6005)

One thing you'll notice is that I moved the RoundedRectange you created into its own view. Hope this makes things easier to read!

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollTest: View {

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(spacing: 25) {
                AnimatedButtonView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnimatedButtonView: View {
    @GestureState var isDetectingLongPress = false
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.5, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(height: 200)
            .padding(25)
            .scaleEffect(!isDetectingLongPress ? 1.0 : 0.875)
            .brightness(!isDetectingLongPress ? 0.0 : -0.125)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.125), value: isDetectingLongPress)
            .delaysTouches(for: 0.1) {
                //some code here, if needed
            }
            .gesture(
                LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 3)
                    .updating($isDetectingLongPress) { currentState, gestureState,
                        transaction in
                        gestureState = currentState
                        transaction.animation = Animation.easeIn(duration: 2.0)
                    }
                    .onEnded { finished in
                        print("pooop")
                    })
        
    }
}

extension View {
    func delaysTouches(for duration: TimeInterval = 0.25, onTap action: @escaping () -> Void = {}) -> some View {
        modifier(DelaysTouches(duration: duration, action: action))
    }
}

fileprivate struct DelaysTouches: ViewModifier {
    @State private var disabled = false
    @State private var touchDownDate: Date? = nil
    
    var duration: TimeInterval
    var action: () -> Void
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        Button(action: action) {
            content
        }
        .buttonStyle(DelaysTouchesButtonStyle(disabled: $disabled, duration: duration, touchDownDate: $touchDownDate))
        .disabled(disabled)
    }
}

fileprivate struct DelaysTouchesButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    @Binding var disabled: Bool
    var duration: TimeInterval
    @Binding var touchDownDate: Date?
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .onChange(of: configuration.isPressed, perform: handleIsPressed)
    }
    
    private func handleIsPressed(isPressed: Bool) {
        if isPressed {
            let date = Date()
            touchDownDate = date
            
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + max(duration, 0)) {
                if date == touchDownDate {
                    disabled = true
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        disabled = false
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            touchDownDate = nil
            disabled = false
        }
    }
}
```

### Approach 2:

Similarly hacky to approach 1. Add a `.onTapGesture` before `.gesture`. Downside is that it adds a delay and I am not sure if that is behavior you are looking for:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ScrollTest: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(spacing: 25) {
                AnimatedButtonView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AnimatedButtonView: View {
    @GestureState var isDetectingLongPress = false
    var body: some View {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12.5, style: .continuous)
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(height: 200)
            .padding(25)
            .scaleEffect(!isDetectingLongPress ? 1.0 : 0.875)
            .brightness(!isDetectingLongPress ? 0.0 : -0.125)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.125), value: isDetectingLongPress)
            .onTapGesture {}
            .gesture(
                LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 3)
                    .updating($isDetectingLongPress) { currentState, gestureState,
                        transaction in
                        gestureState = currentState
                        transaction.animation = Animation.easeIn(duration: 2.0)
                    }
                    .onEnded { finished in
                        print("pooop")
                    })
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried the code and also modified it a bit while I was trying to get the results I wanted, but yes, as you said, it does make the tap delayed for both approaches and that's not what I was looking for. I'll try to find a new way to emulate this without of using `LongPressGesture` since it seems to block scrolling unless it's delayed first. But again, thank you for your interest and I'll try to keep you updated